# ModelBinding a generic type in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, binding

In my views I'm using a generic type for the Model, `ItemModel<T>`.

This allows me to have a basetype on my model and it works fine. Within `ItemModel<T>` I attach the actual entity of T to a property called 'Item'.

Let's say I'm loading a User item: in my view I would like to do something like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Item.NickName, 
new { id="NickName", name="NickName" })%>
```

Because the entity is added via the Item property, this generates the input tag's name attribute as 'Item.NickName'. When posting, MVC can no longer relate this to the User.NickName property of the user object in my controller

```
public ActionResult Login(User user, string redirectUrl)
```

and therefore nothing gets loaded into my User object. Is there a way to fix this? I've been looking into writing a custom bindingmodel or valueprovider, but that looks like alot of work for something this simple. Plus, I'm really not sure if that's that way to go.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change method of your actionresult from

```
public ActionResult Login(User user, string redirectUrl)
```

To

```
public ActionResult Login(User Item, string redirectUrl)
```

this way modelbiner will be able to locate properties of User object prefixed with Item

Comment: This actually works?! It maps "Item.Key" (normally just "Key") to your object.key if you call the instance Item. Is this a documented feature?

Comment: not sure about documentation but learned it the hard way (through experience :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create your helper methods to create that textbox

```
public static MVCString MyTextBox<T>(this HtmlHelper html,T _item,String PropertyName)
{
  TagBuilder myTag  = new TagBuilder("input");
  myTag.Attributes("type")="Text";
  myTag.Attributes("id")=PropertyName;
  myTag.Attributes("name")=PropertyName;
  myTag.Attributes("value")=typeof(_item).GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(_item,null).toString();
  Return MvcHtmlString.Create(selectTag.ToString())
}
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but this is alot of manual work. All my views are using the construct, so I would have to create helpers for every column. What I would really like to do is autmatically Map Item.Anything to Anything.

Comment: I updated my code to be more Generic using .Net reflection. I hope that help you.